# ¿Existe alguna menara de pasarle html a un ckeditor con js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ckeditor

Quiesiera poder pasarle html a un ckeditor para poder dar la opción de editar el texto que estoy escribiendo en ese ckeditor, un ejemplo sería como cuando le damos editar publicación aquí mismo en stackoverflow nos carga todo lo que ya habíamos escrito en el recuadro de texto

```js
let html = `<h2><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</h2>`

$('#editor1').val(html)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>CKEditor</title>
                <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.16.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <textarea name="editor1"></textarea>
                <script>
                        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
                </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Incluso he intentado con `$('#editor1).html(html)`

Hay alguna manera de yo poder pasar el contenido html que tiene esa variable al ckeditor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo necesitas la instancia del editor y el método [.setData()](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-setData).

Puedes usar estas dos opciones:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['id-o-nombre-de-campo'].setData(html);
CKEDITOR.instances.idONombreDeCampo.setData(html);
```

Tu código quedaría así:

```
let html = `<h2><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</h2>`

CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(html);
```

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias, me sirvió las soluciones compartidas